# Dynamics CRM: How to simulate clicking out of a field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a button on my form that takes the values of two other fields. The problem is if I click the button after typing in one of those fields, but before clicking out of it, it takes the value of that field BEFORE I typed in it (usually blank). How would I simulate clicking out of that field using Javascript? I've already tried setting the focus to a different field when the button is clicked (before the rest of my code executed), but for some reason it still takes the old value of the field.

Here is my code structure:

```
function btnCalculate_onClick() {
  Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("zipCodeFieldName").setFocus();

  strStreet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("streetFieldName").getValue();
  strCity = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cityFieldName").getValue();
  strState = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("stateFieldName").getValue();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' + strStreet + ',' + strCity + ',' + strState + '&sensor=false', 
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function() {
      alert('Error loading XML document');
    },
    success: function(xml) {
      // do something with xml
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that strCity is being recognized as `null` unless I first click out of the city field before clicking the button.

Comment: Please post a link or a snippet of code so we have something to look at.

Comment: Just updated my post to include code.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)

Comment: Why '.setFocus()? Also you have it coded so ajax runs instantly, with no time for text inputs to be stable. Your reading the text too fast, so you get null returns. Insert a small delay before calling ajax.

Comment: Because I'm pretty new to all this stuff so I don't know what I'm doing. I figured having the City field lose focus would be equivalent to clicking out of the field. And I would have thought the ajax stuff would run after the `setFocus()` since it's below it. Is there a more proper way than adding `sleep(1000)` to create the delay? @Cypher I will check out the blur event as well, thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding a delay I tried having the `btnCalculate_onClick` function call another function with the Ajax code. It still takes the city as blank until I click out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use

```
function blurActiveControl() {
    var elid = document.activeElement.id;
    if (elid && elid != null && elid != '') document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

Unsupported but safe and effective, usage in your case would be:

```
function btnCalculate_onClick() {
    blurActiveControl();

    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click event with jQuery:

```
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the setFocus thing would have worked. Try this

```
function btnCalculate_onClick() {
    $(document.body).click();

    setTimeout(doAddressStuff, 10);
}

function doAddressStuff() {
    strStreet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("streetFieldName").getValue();
    strCity = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cityFieldName").getValue();
    strState = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("stateFieldName").getValue();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' + strStreet + ',' + strCity + ',' + strState + '&sensor=false', 
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'text',
      timeout: 1000,
      error: function() {
        alert('Error loading XML document');
      },
      success: function(xml) {
        // do something with xml
      }
    });

}
```